# Dajax vs jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I am currently using the dajax/dajaxice plugin for django in order to take care of ajax calls. We are also using jQuery for a lot of UI operations, but decided to keep dajax because of simpler configuration. Are there any advantages to using jquery's ajax functionality? Are there any disadvantages to using dajax?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's Ajax support requires no configuration, but you don't have the "magic" of being able to call a specific actions on the server directly from JavaScript. Instead, you will need to provide actions for each Ajax request. I wouldn't doubt that there is already a jQuery plugin for Django, and if there isn't, you could basically just recreate Dajax in jQuery.

I see no reason to switch to jQuery, if Dajax is working for you, except that it would result in one less dependency. But, does one less dependency make sense for you in terms of rewriting code that already works with Dajax?